# Trying to implement Angular2 module text-mask-addon

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, npm

I am currently trying to implement text-mask-addons into my angular application
https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons

I tried following the npm links suggestion but am having problem importing it

```
import emailMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/emailMask.js'
```

emailMask is coming up as red.

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Could you post your directory structure, and in which file this line is written

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali I just used the npm install command in the following link https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-mask-addons, and so the structure is inside node_modules/text-mask-addons\dist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your systemjs.config.js file, add the package to your map variable as follows:

```
var map = {
    ....
    ...
    ..
    .
    'text-mask-addons': 'node_modules/text-mask-addons' // Add this line
  };
```

Now, you could just write:

```
import emailMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/emailMask.js'
```

Or, you could just supply the full path for the package as Sebastian pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you want to import with relative path, not absolute? In this case prefix with `./`.

Side note: Your path looks off, because it includes your project/root folder and your `dist` folder. Shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: that is the way the example is used in his documentation I am wondering if I am missing anything I am having trouble importing it into the component

Comment: Which doumentation? If you installed it via npm you shouldn't have to add the whole path. Usually the name of the package is enough and <insert your bundler> will be pointed to the correct location via package.json